# How to control chip select and Load DAC signals for a DAC chip?

Tags: digital-logic, analog, dac, logic-analyzer

I have a [DAC7643 (Texas Instruments) - 16-Bit, Dual Voltage Output
DIGITAL-TO-ANALOG CONVERTER](http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/symlink/dac7642.pdf)

I have been mostly unsuccessful with controlling the CS and LDAC signals. I have simulated a circuit for the DAC on MultiSim.

[image]

Kindly advise what is going wrong. The pdf has a table on logic level to set for the control signals to get the right output. After numerous valid combinations, the output voltage still remains 0v.

Comment: To clarify, are you having these problems in the simulator only, or on a real PCB?

Comment: There are specific timing requirements for these signals (among others): have you taken that into account?

Comment: @pipe: I am only simulating at the moment.

Comment: @Peter: Oh yes!!...thanks for pointing that out...will incorporate that now..